# Pasting without quotes for further use of variable in R

Tags: r

I have a variable which is used after it has been formed using `paste`. However after pasting the variable comes insider quotes which makes it unusable. This variable is inside `as.date` so `as.name` is not working. `noquotes` is not working as well. Is there any other way this variable can be used in `as.date` quotes free?

An example:

```
names<-c("dateA","dateB")
dateA<-c("5/30/2014","6/01/2014")
dateB<-c("5/30/2014")
dateZ<-as.data.frame(c("5/30/2014","6/01/2014","6/02/2014"))
names(dateZ)<-"date"
dateZ$date <- as.Date(dateZ$date,"%m/%d/%Y")
for (item in names){
  dateZ[paste(item)] <- ifelse(dateZ$date %in% as.Date(paste(item), format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 1, 0)
}
```

The output is

```
> dateZ
        date dateA dateB
1 2014-05-30     0     0
2 2014-06-01     0     0
3 2014-06-02     0     0
```

However the output I want is

```
       date  dateA  dateB
1 2014-05-30     1     1
2 2014-06-01     1     0
3 2014-06-02     0     0
```

I suspect it is due to the quotes which are staying back because of paste(items). Simply using item yields the same result.

Thanks in advance and sorry for not providing an example before

Comment: Please carefully [read this post](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) and use its advice to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You may also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are other ways, but one way of solving it is by using get(item):

```
for (item in names){
  dateZ[item] <- ifelse(dateZ$date %in% as.Date(get(item), format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 1, 0)
}
```

In this example you don't achieve anything by your use of paste, but the method above will also work if the real case is actually something like item = paste0(item1, item2).